# Javascript to Add the specific cells and display it in the specific cell as well

Tags: javascript, html

Hi What I'm trying to do is from Sc1pts to Sc10pts
here's the link of the Files https://mega.nz/folder/fkcTAaDT#eCaku5ukYsGlg8T8W6U-FA

it should display to the PTS the sum of it
and Jersey # should not be included and Name of players, Name of players should be string only and if
not string set to empty and and alert please enter a name. I've been trying to do this almost three hours still not getting it.

```js
var add = [];
var sum = 0;
var addNum = [];

function addPlayer() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  var cells = table.querySelectorAll("td");
  var row = table.insertRow();
  var count = [];
  for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {

    cells = row.insertCell(i);

    // optional - make the tabel cells editable
    //cells.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);

    if (i > 1) {
      cells = cells.innerHTML = "0";
    }
  }
  addEvents(row);
}

function addPlayer1() {
  var table = document.getElementById("table1");

  var row = table.insertRow();

  for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    cells = row.insertCell(i);

    // optional - make the tabel cells editable
    //cells.setAttribute('contenteditable', true);

    if (i > 1) {
      cells = cells.innerHTML = "0";
    }
  }
  addEvents(row);
}

function addEvents(row) {
  let cells = row.cells;

  for (i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {

    if (cells[i] != cells[12]) {
      cells[i].onclick = function() {
        if (this.hasAttribute("data-clicked")) {
          return;
        }
        this.setAttribute("data-clicked", "yes");
        this.setAttribute("data-text", this.innerHTML);

        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute("type", "text");
        input.value = this.innerHTML;
        input.style.width = this.offsetWidth - this.clientleft * 2 + "px";
        input.style.height = this.offsetHeight - this.clientTop * 2 + "px";
        input.style.border = "0px";
        input.style.fontFamily = "inherit";
        input.style.fontSize = "inherit";
        input.style.textAlign = "inherit";
        input.style.backgroundColor = "LightGoldenRodYellow";

        input.onblur = function() {
          var td = input.parentElement;
          var orig_text = input.parentElement.getAttribute("data-text");
          var current_text = this.value;


          orig_text = parseInt(orig_text);
          current_text = parseInt(current_text);



          if (orig_text != current_text) {
            if (isNaN(current_text)) {
              alert("Please enter a number");
              td.removeAttribute("data-clicked");
              td.removeAttribute("data-text");
              td.innerHTML = "";
              td.style.cssText = "padding: 5px";
            } else {
              //there are changes in the table
              // save our data to our database
              td.removeAttribute("data-clicked");
              td.removeAttribute("data-text");
              td.innerHTML = current_text;
              td.style.cssText = "padding: 5px";

              if (orig_text < current_text || cells[i] != cells[1]) {
                sum += current_text;
                console.log(sum);
              } else if (orig_text > current_text) {
                current_text = orig_text - current_text;
                sum -= current_text;
                console.log(sum);
              }
            }

          }
          //console.log(orig_text + 'is changed to' + current_text);
          else {
            td.removeAttribute("data-clicked");
            td.removeAttribute("data-text");
            td.innerHTML = orig_text;
            td.style.cssText = "padding: 5px";
            if (orig_text < current_text && cells[i] > cells[1]) {
              sum += current_text;
              console.log(sum);
            } else if (orig_text > current_text && cells[i] > cells[1]) {
              current_text = orig_text - current_text;
              sum -= current_text;
              console.log(sum);
            }
          }

          //console.log("No changes made");



        };


        input.addEventListener("keypress", function(event) {
          if (event.key == "Enter") {
            this.blur();
          }
        });

        this.innerHTML = "";
        this.style.cssText = "padding: 0px 0px";
        this.append(input);
        this.firstElementChild.select();
      };
    }
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
  justify-items: center;
}

table,
thead,
tr,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

table,
tbody,
tr,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 5px;
}

table {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: white;
}

th {
  background-color: gray;
  color: white;
}

button {
  margin: 20px;
  background-color: antiquewhite;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}

h1 {
  margin: 2%;
}

.table-containers {
  margin: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=+, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Sports & Games Score Updates</h1>

  <div class="table-containers">
    <table id="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Jersey #</th>
          <th>Name of players</th>
          <th>Sc1pts</th>
          <th>Sc2pts</th>
          <th>Sc3pts</th>
          <th>Sc4pts</th>
          <th>Sc5pts</th>
          <th>Sc6pts</th>
          <th>Sc7pts</th>
          <th>Sc8pts</th>
          <th>Sc9pts</th>
          <th>Sc10pts</th>
          <th>PTS</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <button type="button" onclick="addPlayer()">Add player</button>
  </div>

  <div class="table-containers">
    <table id="table1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Jersey #</th>
          <th>Name of players</th>
          <th>Sc1pts</th>
          <th>Sc2pts</th>
          <th>Sc3pts</th>
          <th>Sc4pts</th>
          <th>Sc5pts</th>
          <th>Sc6pts</th>
          <th>Sc7pts</th>
          <th>Sc8pts</th>
          <th>Sc9pts</th>
          <th>Sc10pts</th>
          <th>PTS</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </tbody>

    </table>
    <button id="addTable" type="button" onclick="addPlayer1()">Add player</button>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `i` is mutated by the time it appears in the callback. Make a variable before the callback is created that clones the number, such as `let iCache = i`

Comment: Do I need to assign it to an array?

Comment: I also want to exclude the cell jersey and name from the isNaN and summing... How do I do that?